# Can I set an environment variable for a container to the value of the clusterIP of a service in my cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to set an environment variable in my container to the IP address provided by a service that is already running in my cluster.

I had this working with the following:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: new_container
      image: my_image:latest
      env:
        - name: ENV_VAR
          value: k8s_service_name
```

I modified the spec to provide the container all host network traffic via:

```
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
    - name: new_container
      image: my_image:latest
      env:
        - name: ENV_VAR
          value: k8s_service_name
```

However, the container no longer seems to understand what 'k8s_service_name' is, so I need to pass the actual IP value of that service.

The address I need is available in the container as K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST=255.255.255.255

But for the application to work I need to make ENV_VAR=255.255.255.255

The following did not work
 `value: $K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST`
 `value: $$K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST`
 `value: $(K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST)`
 `value: {{K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST}}`
 `value: {{env.K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST}}`

Expected:

```
>>> printenv | grep ENV_VAR
ENV_VAR=255.255.255.255
```

Actual Results:

```
>>> printenv | grep ENV_VAR
ENV_VAR=$K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST
```

or errors involving the value not converting from yaml to json properly.

A solution like below would be

```
valueFrom:
  fieldRef:
    fieldName: k8s_service_name.clusterIP
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure, if you set `hostNetwork: true`, the cluster-internal IP addresses will be totally unreachable.  (It may depend on your CNI provider.)  But you can experiment with this by manually setting the variable to the IP address of the service.

Comment: try $(YOUR_VARIABLE) in your yaml. plus if you can - edit the question with your service definition

Comment: @Amityo That worked... `value: $(K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST)`

Comment: Great. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `value: $(K8S_SERVICE_NAME_SERVICE_HOST)`

To get the service ip. (use parenthesis)